# I want to create an Array of Generic classes but it forces my to specify its type

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, class, generics

I'm creating a pod for making easier all the MVVM setup for any new app but I'm having troubles with generic types.

I created a class called representer which function is to register a Cell type to a UITableView and expect an specific kind of data such as:

```
class MRKTVRepresenter<C,D> : NSObject, MRKTVRepresenterProtocol where C : UITableViewCell , D : Any {

    public private(set) var representType = C.self

    public func registerRepresenter(_ tv: UITableView) {
        tv.registerClassNib(representType)
    }

    public func rehuseCellFor(tv:UITableView, at index:IndexPath, with data:D )->C{
        let cell = tv.dequeueReusableCell(representType, for: index)
        return representCellFor(tv: tv, at: index, in: cell, with: data)
    }
}
```

Then when in my TableView datasource I wanna have an Array of representers such as:

```
open class MRKTVDatasource: NSObject, UITableViewDataSource {
    public var representers : [MRKTVRepresenter] {
        return []
    }
}
```

But when I do, it tells me I have to specify its type, and If I specify that the expected type is a UITableViewCell type, It will throw an error if the Representer Uses a different type, even if it extends from UITableViewCell.

How could I solve this?

Thank you very much!

Comment: `Any` is not generic. A generic type can be *any* **static** type which is passed at runtime. A protocol with associated types might be more suitable for your needs.

Comment: In the end, I solved this problem by using a protocol which receives a Data of type Any and it is the Class which implements this protocol the one that casts the data.
Even though I didn't know about associated types, and now I do thanks to you, and will probably very useful in the future. Thanks a lot!